# Excluir un resultado en una consulta - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

estoy haciendo que me muestre en la vista de un producto, los productos relacionados de forma aleatoria y limitandolo a cuatro. Pero puedo excluir el producto que estoy viendo?? No se si hay una condición `where` para excluir.

```
public function verRopa($id, $titulo)
 {  

$producto = Product::join('categories', 'products.categoria', '=', 'categories.id')
                            ->select('products.*', 'categories.name as nombreCategoria', 'categories.id AS idCategory')
                            ->where('products.id', $id)->where('products.slug', $titulo)->first();  
$contador = Cart::count();
  if(Auth::guest() || auth()->user()->tipo_id == 0 || auth()->user()->tipo_id == 3) {
     $random = Product::inRandomOrder()->limit(4)->where('categoria', $producto->idCategory)->where('visiblePara', 3)->where('estado', 1)->get();
   }
  }
```

Como traigo la `id` que estoy viendo al controlador puedo hacer algo creo, alguna sugerencia?

Estoy probando con `->whereNotIn('id', $id)` pero me devuelve error.

Comment: Si estoy visionando la vista de un producto completo, al final de esa vista pongo un módulo con cuatro productos relacionados, de esos relacionados quiero suprimir el que estoy viendo

Comment: Hay primero un listado y cuando le doy al botón para ver el producto, obtengo la id, y el controlado me muestra toda la información en la página nueva de está id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes por medio del *query builder* hacer uso del método [`whereNotIn`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) dentro del cual indicamos la columna deseada y en formato de *array* pasamos la variable por medio de la cual vamos a componer el filtro.

```
$random = Product::inRandomOrder()
                ->whereCategoria($producto->idCategory)
                ->whereVisiblePara(3)
                ->whereEstado(1)
                ->whereNotIn('id', [$idProductoActual])
                ->limit(4)
                ->get();
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto @BetaM no conocia que se pudiese hacer `whereCategoria` es la primera vez que lo veo, aunque no lo puedo gastar por que me lo combierte a nombres que no existen, pero funciona perfectamente `->whereNotIn('id', [$id])'  gracias como siempre!